# Solution set for Kleene star over language $L = \{w \in \sum^*| \exists x\in \Sigma. |w|_x=0\}$ with $\Sigma = \{a,b,c\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, formal-languages, regular-language, context-free-grammar

When reviewing the solutions to an exercise of theoretical informatics, I was stumbling over something I don't understand.

Given a language $L = \{w \in \sum^*| \exists x\in \Sigma. |w|_x=0\}$ with $\Sigma = \{a,b,c\}$ you should draw an NFA. The following NFA was given in the solution: [NFA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVH4p.png)

What I don't understand is, why the sample space, as the NFA suggests, isn't containing combinations from all letters (e.g. abc, cbba etc.). As I learned $\sum^* = \bigcup_{n\in \Bbb N}$$\sum^n$ and therefore shouldn't it be $\sum^*=\{\epsilon, a, b, c, aa, ab, ac, ba, bb, bc, ca, cb, cc, aaa, aab, aac, aba, abb,$ **abc**$, \ldots\}$?

Thanks in advance for clearing this out!

Comment: What does $|w|_x$ mean

Comment: Your are right about $\Sigma^*$, but I need to know what $|w|_x$ means first

Comment: It means the length of a word (amount of characters). As |w|=0 is possible, the NFA's entry state is an end state.

Comment: So are you telling me that the language only contains strings of length $0$?

Comment: No, just that it is possible. ($\exists x \in \epsilon$ with $|w|_x = 0$ means $\epsilon$ is in the set and there is a production $q_0 \to \epsilon$)

Comment: No, that's not what it means. $|w|_x $ is the number of occurrences of the letter  $x $ in the string (word) $w $.

Comment: Ah thats the thing I got wrong and the reason why the given solution is correct (you first decide on which letter isn't occurring in the word and then just iterate over the others). Thanks @AndrésE.Caicedo

Answer (score 0):

In that case, then your $NFA$ is correct, rather the one you linked in $wrong$.

Here is a better example:

[image]

And $q_0$ is starting state ... forgot to draw the arrow